# Issues with spawning multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Are there any issues with spawning multiple threads using `threading.Thread`?

E.g. everytime a wx.SpinCtrl is clicked? I don't know of an implementation that enables you to keep the thread alive and to start the main method multiple times.

PS: I think a [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) implicits that it's not so bad.

Comment: Can you post an example of the type of work that you want to do on a click?

Comment: I can't post code, now. I want to generate an image by some values and set it on a wx.Bitmap for every queue position, and then reduce the queue everytime. I think it could last about a second. +++ Calling `threading.Thread(target=...)` is easy, so it's my first thought. But is it bad for the system, e.g. making it slow? Or is it like calling a method?

Answer (score 1):

'C++'-like pseudo:

Thread:

```
Tthread::run(){
  while(true){
    semaphore.wait();
    mainMethod();
  };
};
```

GUI:

```
MyForm::OnSpinCtrlClick(Control sender){
  semaphore.signal();
};
```

The mainMethod() will run exactly as many times as you click.

Comment: As I found out over time, this can require more than one event to wait on (e.g. when starting again the thread could still run or not, or when asking whether it's running). It's too complex for me, now, to digest this topic.